# D3 Coding Order

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dimple.js

I am not clear about the pattern in which a D3 code must be written.

**for e.g** *In the below code snippet, If I mention the 3rd section(Chart Title) of the code after creating the svg element my chart doesn't show the title text but If i mention the 3rd section before creating the svg it simply works.*

**Why ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

    circle.dimple-series-1{
    fill: red;
    }    

    h2{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    }   

    </style>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(data) {

      /*
        D3.js setup code
      */

          "use strict";
          var margin = 75,
              width = 1400 - margin,
              height = 600 - margin;

          /*TITLE*/

          d3.select("body")
          .append("h2").text("Goals by Year!");

          /*Creating SVG*/

          var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin)
              .attr("height", height + margin)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','chart');

      /*
        Dimple.js Chart construction code
      */

          var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
          var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "year"); 
          x.dateParseFormat="%Y"
          x.tickFormat="%Y";
          x.timeInterval= 4;
          myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "attendance");
          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.scatter);


          myChart.draw();
        };
      </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    Use D3 (not dimple.js) to load the TSV file
    and pass the contents of it to the draw function
    */
  d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", draw);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the bit that doesn't work (and clarify 'doesn't work', is there any error) ? Maybe add it as commented code in the example.

Comment: I did hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds like in the case where it doesn't work the SVG is overlapping the text. You may want to set the positioning explicitly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So do you mean, since my Title text is above the SVG and since the svg has no element appended to it , the title is visible?

Comment: I am a little unclear with the exact visual representation, but you should note that SVG are layer dependent and that the is no ability to use z-indexing. More info @ http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/renderorder/SVGRenderOrder.html

Comment: No, when you add the title first, the automatic layout of HTML works as expected. When you add the SVG first, it doesn't.

Comment: @ryan0319 I understand the SVG rendering order (article you cited) but the piece that I am unclear about is, I understand SVG as a canvas and I am allowed to draw on it. So, why cant I draw title text after creating SVG element. Why should I mention Chart title text code before creating SVG?

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz I ran it both ways. I can create the title above and below the SVG by moving the code block above or below the SVG creation. Where do you actually want the title? Do you want it to be an actual part of the graph or outside of the SVG context?

Comment: I have mentioned the complete code in the Question. If I place title code below the creating svg code, Title doesn't appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is not added to the svg. You are appending a heading object to the body.  The only reason I can think it wouldn't appear once you have added the SVG is because it is being added after it in the DOM so might be out of sight?  It depends on your CSS, but I'm fairly sure the element will still be added.

In the first case your DOM will look like this:

```
<body>
    <h2>Goals by Year!</h2>
    <svg>
       <... Dimple Stuff ...>
    </svg>
</body>
```

and in the second case like this:

```
<body>
    <svg>
       <... Dimple Stuff ...>
    </svg>
    <h2>Goals by Year!</h2>
</body>
```

If you want to add your title to the SVG itself you need to use SVG shapes and you need to target the SVG instead of body.  E.g:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin)
        .attr("height", height + margin);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("Goals by Year!");

... Dimple Stuff
```

In this case your DOM will look like this:

```
<body>
    <svg>
       <text x=100 y=100 style="fill:black">Goals by Year!</text>
       <... Dimple Stuff ...>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Edit: Removed note.  Dimple seems fine with using a group inside the svg.